# ORACLE ODI - ORA -00904-invalid-identifier

Tags: oracle

New to oracle. I have a dimension with a primary key. I create an interface. Mapping from staging area to analytics area. I set the primary key for target to execute on target. I click active mapping and set mapping to ROWNUM via the expression editor so the mapping looks like a screen shot I have.

When I execute I'm getting the above error and I've reached a dead end. Can anyone help? I don't want to map it to anything. I just want it to have a int ID created when records are inserted

Thanks

Debbie

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Comment: Sorted. I used the wrong IKM selector within interfaces - flow. I needed to use IKM SQL CONTROL APPEND.